# Code Snippet String Functions Not Working?

Tags: php, string, code-snippets

Every letter has a number. You write a sentence and you get the sum of the letters.

The $phrase appears in lowercase for same reason. The $sum is always zero and I don't understand why this happens. Do you have any idea what's wrong?

I use code snippets in WordPress

```
add_shortcode( 'infotable', function () {

    $phrase = strtoupper($_GET['phrase']);
    
    $length = strlen($phrase);
    $sum = 0;
    $bottom = 0;
    
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        switch($phrase{$i}) {
            case 'Α': case 'Ά': $sum += 1; break;
            case 'Β': $sum += 2; break;
            case 'Γ': $sum += 3; break;
            case 'Δ': $sum += 4; break;
            case 'Ε': case 'Έ': $sum += 5; break;
            case 'Ζ': $sum += 7; break;
            case 'Η': case 'Ή': $sum += 8; break;
            case 'Θ': $sum += 9; break;
            case 'Ι': case 'Ί': case 'Ϊ': $sum += 10; break;
            case 'Κ': $sum += 20; break;
            case 'Λ': $sum += 30; break;
            case 'Μ': $sum += 40; break;
            case 'Ν': $sum += 50; break;
            case 'Ξ': $sum += 60; break;
            case 'Ο': case 'Ό': $sum += 70; break;
            case 'Π': $sum += 80; break;
            case 'Ρ': $sum += 100; break;
            case 'Σ': $sum += 200; break;
            case 'Τ': $sum += 300; break;
            case 'Υ': case 'Ύ': case 'Ϋ': $sum += 400; break;
            case 'Φ': $sum += 500; break;
            case 'Χ': $sum += 600; break;
            case 'Ψ': $sum += 700; break;
            case 'Ω': case 'Ώ': $sum += 800; break;
            default:  break;
        }
    }
    
    $out = '<section>
        <h4>ΠΡΟΤΑΣΗ</h4>
        <h4>' . $phrase . '
        <h4>ΑΞΙΑ</h4>
        <h4>' . $sum . '</h4>
        <h4>ΠΥΘΜΕΝΙΚΟΣ</h4>
        <h4>' . $bottom . '</h4>
    </section>';

    return $out;
} );
```

Comment: Maybe if you change $phrase{$i} to $phrase[$i]

Comment: I tried that but it doesnt work. I read that in php you should use {} to access a string's characters

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that cyrillic characters have a larger byte offset than ascii characters.

Take the following:

```
$p = 'ΠΡΟΤΑΣΗ';
$phrase = strtoupper($p);

$length = strlen($phrase);
echo($length);

$p = 'ΠΡΟΤΑΣΗ';
$phrase = strtoupper($p);

$length = strlen($phrase);
echo($length);

for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
    echo($phrase{$i});
    echo($phrase[$i]);
}
```

This will output:

```
14

�
�

�
�

�
�

�
�

�
�

�
�

�
�

�
�

�
�

�
�

�
�

�
�

�
�

�
�
```

You can use `str_split()` which will allow you to specify the byte offest instead like this:

```
$p = 'ΠΡΟΤΑΣΗ';
$phrase = strtoupper($p);

$phraseArray = str_split( $phrase, 2 );
$length = count($phraseArray);

echo($length);

for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
    echo("<p>" . $phraseArray{$i});
    echo("<br>" . $phraseArray[$i]);
}
```

Which yields this output:

```
7

Π
Π

Ρ
Ρ

Ο
Ο

Τ
Τ

Α
Α

Σ
Σ

Η
Η
```

Comment: Well, okay the phrase is shown, but what about the $sum and $bottom? Do you have any idea?

To be accurate these are Greek characters

Comment: Sorry, my mistake on the character set. I'm not really clear on what `$bottom` is being used for, so I can't really comment on that. As for `$sum`, you can put your switch statement into the for loop in my code sample and you should get proper sums. Your previous code wasn't working because none of the case statements were matching the single byte for a given character.